# Can I use a Grafana table to list all nodes reporting to Prometheus?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I use the [Node Exporter Server Metrics](https://grafana.com/dashboards/405) dashboard for visualizing server metrics from prometheus.

I'd like to build a table that lists out all nodes that are reporting a certain job and links to the server metrics dashboard for that node.

I've been trying to do a query like: `up{job="telemetry-node"}`. The problem is that the return of that is simply the value `"1"`, because the node is up, so the table wants to list timeseries data, I can't figure out a query that would return info about the node in a way that I could display it in a table.

I got this working in a hacky way by setting the `Legend Format` to `{{instance}}` to list the instance name as `Metric` in the table, set `override relative time` to `1s`, and used column styling to hide `Time` and `Value`. I'd really like to find a better solution.

With either a proper solution or my hackjob above is there a way for me to format the contents of the table to be a link to another dashboard? I see that I can set a `Drilldown Link` in the `General` settings but that seems to be for the panel, not individual entries in the table.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a very [early version of a plugin that can link table rows](https://github.com/dmitrios/grafana-plugins-reftable) to do what you want (but I haven't tried that one yet).

What you can do with Grafana out of the box:

- Create a [template variable for your dashboard](http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/prometheus/#templating) with a query `label_values(instance)` that provides you all instances. and make it "multiple values" and to "include all values" to use the repeat option below. You can later hide it and pass it as a URL parameter.
- Have a row or any panel that [repeats itself using the template variable](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/)
- On each Panel you can add one Drilldown Link. In a Text Panel you can create a direct HTML link. You can pass the current value of the template variable to the link.